# Multiple controllers under single module in Zendframework2

Tags: zend-framework2

I went through ZF tutorial for creating Album.
The structure would be as below :-

```
module/
    Album/
         config/
             module.config.php
         src/
            Album/
                Controller/
                         AlbumController.php
        view/
            album/ ....             
        Module.php
```

I need to create one more controller called UserController.php under src/Album/Controller/
IS this possible? Is this the right way to do in Zendframework2?

Answer (score 0):

You need to define the new controller in the `module.config.php`

```
'controllers'  => array(
    'invokables' => array(

        [... some other controller defined here too ...]

        'Album\Controller\User' => 'Album\Controller\UserController',
    )
)
```

then you create your new Controller in `Album/src/Album/Controller/` and name it UserController.php. The file becomes the namespace and the class name:

`namespace Album\Controller;`

`class UserController extends \Zend\Mvc\Controller\AbstractActionController`

and some `indexAction` method witch returns a `new \Zend\View\Model\ViewModel();`

then you can create your viewfile in

`Album/view/Album/user/index.phtml`

and yes, this is the normal procedure to add a new controller to a module.

Comment: In the albumcontroller, I have already user namespace Album\COntroller

So shoudl I user new namespace??

Comment: you need to add the namespace to the new controller file "UserController.php" not to the other Controller "AlbumController.php" - if the namespace is allready set in your "UserController.php" then u can keep it and jump over this step

Comment: But my albumcontroller doesnt work if I remove the namespace Album\Controller

Comment: the namespace for all controllers in your Album Module ist `namespace Album\Controller` u dont need to edit your namespace on existing Controller files u need to add this namespace to the new Controller PHP File if u create one

Comment: I tried doing, but when I hit localhost/user, I get blank page

Comment: check your created files of writing mistakes, is a route set for `/user` u use the route `/[:controller[/:action]]` in your Application/config/module.config.php? Error Reporting on?

Comment: otherwise walk the tutorial from the zf2 doc about controllers and routing http://framework.zend.com/manual/2.0/en/user-guide/routing-and-controllers.html

Comment: i did all the changed as you mentioned here. is there any chage needed in "Album/Module.php" file ?